# PHP and secure forms

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I am doing an exercise from the book PHP & MYSQL in easy steps. It involves an HTML form to update a row in a database then various PHP scripts to check the the input data for HTML code and make it into a secure format. However, the code just does not work the way the book says. I went to the publisher's website and downloaded the code example, but no joy.

Instead of a form with the name of the row below it, instead I get the form, then below that "No valid new name submitted". Then below that the current name of row in the table which I want to change. When I try to enter and submit data into the form it makes no difference. It displays exactly the same page. The code is below.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Ensuring security
    </title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="secure.php" method="POST">
    <p>New Name : <input type="text" name="name">
        <input type="submit"></p></form>



<?php

require('../connect_db.php');


if (!empty($POST['name']) && !is_numeric($_POST['name'])) {
    $name = $POST['name'];

    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $name);
    $name = strip_tags($name);

    $q = 'UPDATE towels SET name "' . $name . '" WHERE id= 1';
    mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
} else {
    echo 'No valid new name submitted';
}

$q = 'SELECT * FROM towels WHERE id = 1 ';
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_NUM)) {
    echo "<p>Name : $row[1] </p>";
}
mysqli_close($dbc);
```

I'd appreciate any ideas on this. I have spent about 3 hours and been on the publishers website, but I am still at square one.

Comment: Get a different book. One that teaches [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). (Not to mention the mix of HTML and PHP which makes stuff unreadable and unmaintainable.)

Comment: You're using `mysqli` wrong. You should be preparing a statement and then using [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add the `$name` value. Using string concatenation is extremely hazardous as a simple mistake can be devastating. If you're learning this technique from a book, your book is broken. I'm with Bart here, get a new book.

Comment: For starters, change all `$POST` to `$_POST`

Comment: Please tell us which book is it (title and author).

Comment: I just downloaded what I assume is the same code from http://ineasysteps.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/php-src.zip  and it works fine and also has a different value for the `title` element : `<title>PHP Security</title>`.  So first, everyone who is assuming that the book must be bogus just like any other resource for beginners is so lame should stand down. Second, Troy, were you modifying the code to get your hands dirty or copying it straight from the book originally?

Comment: @ElonThan - The book is _PHP & MySQL in Easy Steps_ like the OP says straight off. I happen to own it and I learned a thing or two from w3schools back in the day as well. Check it out: http://www.amazon.com/MySQL-Easy-Steps-Mike-McGrath/dp/1840785373

Comment: @Anthony He said `I went to the publisher's website and downloaded the code example, but no joy` so I assume that he did not modify that code. But maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: He also says he was practicing from the book and it wasn't working so he downloaded the code from their site. And given that I just downloaded the code from the publisher's website and the URL has the date in it, unless they are monitor SO and are *really* fast, my money is on a simple transcription error by someone trying to learn and that we should not sh*t all over resources and make the OP lose confidence, as we occasionally do around here.

Comment: Hi guys, the "$POST" error was mine. I have fixed that but the page still displays the way I described it above. The only difference now is when I submit form with the name change the ""No valid new name submitted" message disappears. However, it is still displaying the old name for that row. It seems is is not processing the name change. Can anyone recommend an alternative book?? I decided to stick with this as a basis for getting the basics down. I don't think I  made any other mistakes and I was really trying to copy the  code rather than play about with it.

Answer (score 5):

There is no superglobal array `$POST` so you have to change `$POST['name']` to `$_POST['name']`.

PHP can't see that array so it evaluates `!empty($POST['name'])` as `false` and never executes code with `update` query.

And, like @BartFriederichs said, buy better book. I don't think you'll learn something valuable from current one.

Comment: Thanks. I have already commented above. I corrected the error, but it still does not process the name change. I am not sure which book I will go with next.